# Unix command to generate cryptographically secure random string

Tags: cryptography, linux, random, unix

Is the following Unix command cryptographically secure to randomly generate 20 characters (a-zA-Z0-9 only)?

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=256 count=1 2> /dev/null | LC_ALL=C tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9' | head -c20
```

Is there a better or more secure way to go about this in Unix?

Comment: I use https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476125/9583 - you could easily grab 20 characters off the end for > 116.65 bits of entropy; less than the accepted answer, but with other nice properties as in my post.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, it's not entirely secure. Let's look at each of the commands:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=256 count=1 2> /dev/null
```

This will read a single 256 byte block from `/dev/urandom`, a cryptographically secure random source. The problem starts here, and is related to this 256 byte limit. In fact, you do not even need to use `dd` here. The next command is perfectly able to read from a block device on its own.

```
LC_ALL=C tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9'
```

This command strips out all characters that are not alphanumeric. The `LC_ALL=C` [limits the charset](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87763/277264) to plain ASCII, where `[:alnum:]` will match 62 characters. Symbols and unprintable characters will be removed. The issue now is that only 256 bytes are given to this command, so what if too few of those bytes are alphanumeric? The `tr` command will happily take 256 bytes of input and spit out only a couple bytes of output if only a couple bytes match the filter.

```
head -c20
```

This command simply truncates the output to 20 bytes. The actual output will vary between 0 and 20 characters.* Statistically, it is most likely for it to output the entire 20 characters each time.

---

A superior way to get random alphanumeric characters can be done with fewer commands. This will have `tr` read as much data from `/dev/urandom` as it needs, continuously spitting out alphanumeric ASCII to the next command. As soon as `head` has the 20 bytes it has asked for, it will close the pipe, causing `tr` to stop reading random data and exit. This is what you should use:

```
LC_ALL=C tr -dc '[:alnum:]' < /dev/urandom | head -c20
```

This will guarantee 20 random characters, with an equivalent strength of log<sub>2</sub>(62<sup>20</sup>) ≈ 119.1 bits.

You can also turn this into a shell script function to make password generation from command line easier. This particular function is for bash and takes the number of characters for the password as an argument. If no argument is specified, it defaults to 20 characters:

```
newpass() {
    LC_ALL=C tr -dc '[:alnum:]' < /dev/urandom | head -c${1:-20}
}
```

<sub>* The risk is largely theoretical. Each byte has a (256 - 62) / 256 chance (about 76%) of *not* being alphanumeric. The probability that at least 256 - 20 bytes are not alphanumeric is very low, but non-zero: (194 / 256)<sup>236</sup> ≈ 3.8 × 10<sup>-28</sup>.</sub>

Comment: Noticed when using `random=$(LC_ALL=C tr -dc '[:alnum:]' < /dev/urandom | head -c20)` in a bash script with `set -eo pipefail; [[ $TRACE ]] && set -x` causes the script to fail with a non-0 exit code. Any ideas why that is?

Comment: @Justin This happens because `head` closes the pipe as soon as 20 bytes have been read, which causes `tr` to exit with a broken pipe (after all, `head` is no longer listening). This is totally normal and expected behavior. When you use `pipefail`, that turns it into a fatal error.

Comment: So if I use `set -e; [[ $TRACE ]] && set -x` instead that seems to work.

Comment: why not just use pwgen -s 20 1?

Comment: @ShaneAndrie SUS XCU7 does not specify `pwgen`, but it does specify `tr` and `head`.

Comment: @forest Can you explain SUS XCU7 for reference?

Comment: @ShaneAndrie The SUS is the Single Unix Specification, a standard for all *nix operating systems. XCU is specifically the utilities that must be pre-installed on the system.

Comment: The suggested commands didn't work in my case. They just returned with no output. I used this version instead: `< /dev/random stdbuf -o0 strings --bytes 1 | stdbuf -o0 tr -d '\n\t '`

Comment: @rubik What shell are you using? It works correctly for me using bash and ash.w

Comment: @forest I use Zsh, maybe that is the reason.

Comment: @rubik Have you tried replacing `[:alnum:]` with `a-zA-Z0-9`? That is necessary for some shells.

Comment: @forest Yep, does not work. For some reason the command always returns with no output.

Comment: @rubik That's very odd. Try `set -x; tr -cd 'a-zA-Z0-9' < /dev/urandom | head -c20` to view the debugging output. The command itself is very simple, so I can't imagine what could be going wrong. As long as you have a readable random device and shell redirections are supported, this should work. The `tr` and `head` commands' behavior are part of a strict standard.

Comment: I added limited punctuation to make password registration sites happy, without annoying shell scripts.  The tr string in my command is now `'[:alnum:]-=~@,._'`