# Cryptographically secure password generation

Tags: passwords

I saw [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/183948/unix-command-to-generate-cryptographically-secure-random-string) post here that mentions one method of generating cryptographically secure passwords. Recently, I was given a similar task and took a different approach.

One of the answers in that questions used the following

```
tr -dc '[:alnum:]' < /dev/urandom | head -c20
```

My method looked more like the following:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs="$password_length" count=1 | base64
```

I didn't have a requirement for it to be alphanumeric-only, and no requirement for it to contain symbols or anything like that. The only requirements were that it's 8 characters minimum (I went with 80 in practice because, if it only needs to be read/used by a machine, why not?), and hard to guess.

Is there any (cryptographically significant) difference between the two methods (aside from length)?

Answer (score 2):

Aside from length, no there is no difference at all. The former generates a 20 character password with a keyspace of 62<sup>20</sup>, whereas the latter generates a password with a keyspace of 2<sup>8×bytes</sup>. Assuming *bytes* is at least 16, you will get 128 bits of entropy which is considered a safe minimum. Both these commands get their entropy directly from `/dev/urandom`. However, you do not need to use `dd` for this purpose which is rather inefficient. You can safely and slightly more efficiently use:

```
head -c"$bytes" /dev/urandom | base64
```

Comment: `[:alnum:]` is 62 in an ASCII-only locale like C or POSIX, and more in a non-English but single-byte (usable with urandom) locale.

Comment: Wow, I just realized I had been thinking of the alphabet as having 24 characters, not 26. I've been staring at too much disassembly...